# How to use pack in vs and gcc

Tags: c++, structure, packing

Until today I used this following technique to pack structures:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct mystruct
{
     char a1;
     char a2;
     int a3;
}
#pragma pack(pop)

mystruct mydata()
{ 
   mystruct ms;
   ms.a1='a';
   ms.a2='b';
   ms.a3=12;
   return ms;
 }
```

and assumed that ms packed as 1, but today somebody told me that in the above definition, ms is packed as 4, since pack has no effect on definition, but on declaration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Can somebody clarify if what I did was correct or not?

Comment: Every definition is also a declaration.

Comment: @n.m.  what do you mean? Can you elaborate? If there is no difference, why we call them definition and declaration?

Comment: @mans A definition is a declaration.  Not all declarations are definitions.  And I can't figure out what MS means on the man page you cite.  (But then, I can't think of any possible reason to use `pack` either.)

Comment: Because not every declaration is a definition.

Answer (score 1):

The standard specifies §3.1/2

> **A declaration is a definition** unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it
>   contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification25 (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a functionbody,
>   it declares a static data member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is
>   an opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), it is a template-parameter (14.1), it is a parameter-declaration (8.3.5) in a
>   function declarator that is not the declarator of a function-definition, or it is a typedef declaration (7.1.3),
>   an alias-declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration (7.3.3), a static_assert-declaration (Clause 7), an attributedeclaration
>   (Clause 7), an empty-declaration (Clause 7), or a using-directive (7.3.4).

thus you have a structure definition as you correctly noted, but it is also a declaration so the case

> pack has no effect on definitions

applies, but not for the declaration. In fact MSVC and gcc/clang correctly pack the above with 1

```
struct mystruct_not_packed
{
    char a1;
    char a2;
    int a3;
};

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct mystruct
{
    char a1;
    char a2;
    int a3;
};

mystruct_not_packed object; // This doesn't apply
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(mystruct) << std::endl; // 6
    std::cout << sizeof(mystruct_not_packed) << std::endl; // 8
    std::cout << sizeof(object) << std::endl; // 8
}
```

*(tested with MSVC2013U4)*

<kbd>[Example with gcc](http://ideone.com/pKgjPJ)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *"the pragma has no effect on definitions"* means that if you write

```
struct mystruct
{
    char a1;
    char a2;
    int a3;
};

#pragma pack(push,1)
mystruct ms;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

It will not affect packing of `ms`.

But in your example `ms` will be packed at 1, that's the whole point of `pragma pack`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7438c2e41d903d10)

(MSVC 2013 outputs `8 6` on that code as well as clang and gcc on coliru)

Comment: @MarcoA. and the question asks for gcc as well.

Comment: Right, it's in the title. Although it links MSVC's documentation

Comment: That's _not_ what the doc he linked to said.  It's probably what was meant, but it's not what was said.